# C++11 difference between <thread> get_id() and native_handle()

Tags: multithreading, c++11

What is the difference between C++11  functions `get_id()` and `native_handle()`?

In the test program I created they return the same `int` value for their threads so I have no idea what the difference is.

I'm using GCC 4.8.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread):

> `get_id` returns the id of the thread

and

> `native_handle`   returns the underlying implementation-defined thread handle

The thread identifier as returned by [`get_id`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id) should actually be a class ([`std::thread::id`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id)) and not a number or other platform specific handle.

The [`native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) function returns just what its name implies, a native handle that can be used by the underlying operating systems thread functions. On Windows this is typically a `HANDLE` as returned by [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on POSIX platforms it's typically a `pthread_t` as initialized by [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html).